# Does Java JAR manifest accept multiple jars as Wildcard parameter

Tags: java, classpath, manifest

I tried adding a wildcarded `Class-Path` to my manifest.

`Class-Path: . ../webapps/ROOT/lib/*'

But when I was trying to refer to one of the jars in the wildcarded name. I got a `ClassNotFoundException`.

I was under the impression that from JDK6 onwards, java does support wildcarded classpath. Have I done something wrong here? or Do I need to list all individually?

Comment: No... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Comment: The value of the Class-Path attribute is a space-separated list of relative URLs.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/specs/jar/jar.html#class-path-attribute.